# JQuery - How to call data from modal show into modal keyup function

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I am using JQuery modal and some other functions. Ther, I have this code:

```html
@foreach($goals as $key => $goal)
<tr>
  <td class="myRatingLimit">
    {{ $goal->goaltype->ratingLimit ? $goal->goaltype->ratingLimit->max_rating : '' }}
  </td>
  <td class="myWeightedScore">
    {{$goal->weighted_score ?? '' }}
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" data-target="#modal_add_comment" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ $goal->id }}" data-original-title="Comment">
      <i class="fas text-white">Add Comment</i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And also this modal form is generated from it:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_add_comment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_year_end_setups.employee_year_end_comment',['id'=>$goal->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="review_comment-form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="modal-header">
          Self-Review Comment
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"> Rating:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" id="InputRatingLimit">
            <input type="hidden" id="InputWeightedScore">
            <input type="text" id="myRating" name="employee_year_end_weighted_score" class="form-control myRating" placeholder="Enter Rating here e.g. 10" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
              style="width: 100%;" maxlength="4" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-modal-create" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" id="review_comment_btn-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ok">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#modal_add_comment').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var $this = $(e.relatedTarget);
      var data_id = $this.data('id');
      var modal = $('#modal_add_comment');

      var parentTr = $this.closest('tr');
      var myRatingLimit = parentTr.find('.myRatingLimit').text();
      var myWeightedScore = parentTr.find('.myWeightedScore').text();

      // directly use .val() instead of .attr()
      modal.find('#InputRatingLimit').val(myRatingLimit);
      modal.find('#InputWeightedScore').val(myWeightedScore);

    });

    $('#myRating').keyup(function() {


    });

  }); <
/script>
```

On #myRating keyup, I want to perform this calculation:

```
var main = $("#myWeightedScore").val();
var perc = $("#myRatingLimit").val();
console.log(main);
console.log(perc);
main = main ? parseInt(main) : 0;
perc = perc ? parseInt(perc) : 0;
let sumWeightBalance = parseInt(main);
let sumPercBalance = parseInt(perc);
var percVal = (sumPercBalance / 100).toFixed(2);
var mult = main * percVal;
var percResult = main + mult;
let sumValue = parseInt(value);
```

I want the calculations to be done on $('#myRating').keyup(function() {

How do I now transfer or call the:

```
    var myRatingLimit = parentTr.find('.myRatingLimit').text();
    var myWeightedScore = parentTr.find('.myWeightedScore').text();
```

from

$('#modal_add_comment').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

into

$('#myRating').keyup(function() {

on keyup in order to perform the calculations?
and also convert it into val()

Thanks

Comment: You are already putting those values inside  modal `input-box` why not simply get it using `$("#InputWeightedScore").val()` and `$("#InputRatingLimit").val()` ?

Comment: @Swati - When I did this:               $("#myRating").on('keyup blur', function (e) {  
    var main = $("#InputWeightedScore").val();
    var perc = $("#InputRatingLimit").val();
    main = main ? parseInt(main) : 0;
    perc = perc ? parseInt(perc) : 0;
    let sumWeightBalance = parseInt(main);
    let sumPercBalance = parseInt(perc);
    var percVal = (sumPercBalance / 100).toFixed(2);
    var mult = main * percVal;
    var percResult = main + mult;
    let sumValue = parseInt(value);
    }
      });   I got this error: value is not defined

Comment: from where are getting `value`  i.e : `let sumValue = parseInt(value); ` ?